# HDFS for cold storage and retrieval

Tags: hadoop, binary, hive, sqoop

I have a need to ingest data from the DB2 database on a daily basis into HDFS with necessary partitions folders or hive partitions. For example, partitions based on line of business (LOB), state, date in the order. The DB2 table contains a blob column that stores the GZip compressed XML. Once the data is ingested, the requirement is also to retrieve on a daily basis or so, based on the partition columns and some value withing the XML. The query or retrieval process need not be based on all partition columns; It can be just based on LOB and state but not on the date. This retrieved data based on the state, for example, can be huge (compressed - 160 GB, decompressed - 1600 GB).

**Requirement Summary:**

1. Data Ingestion from DB2 table on a daily basis into HDFS with partitioned folders.
2. The table contains the blob column (that contains the GZIP compressed XML)
3. Hold data in HDFS for X number of years (potentially ~40 TB worth of data)
4. Retrieve the data based on some pre-defined query (Hive/MR)
5. Periodically, the XMLs also have to be converted and it may be needed to store multiple versions of the same.

**Solution that i am thinking:**

*Ingestion:*

1. Sqoop job to ingest the data on a daily basis in avro format to allow for binary import - Landing Zone (purged after the process)
2. Move the data from landing zone to another hive table with necessary partitions (dynamic partitions movement) - Base Table. This is a table with Snappy compressed and avro format. During this step, the compressed xml in the landing zone would decompressed and stored in the base table but the base table itself is compressed.

AVRO is chosen because sqoop import of binary as sequence file format stores the binary in sqoop-specific format and the same decompression code used for avro does not work for sequence file. ORC is another option but i would want the flexibility of processing in MR as well not just with hive.

Any thoughts around this?

*Retrieval:*

Since sqoop does not support binary export to DB2, i have these options for export

1. Exporting the data as a text file into some some file server (needs data movement from HDFS to the edge node and then to the file server).

   Sub-option: Text file thats GZip compressed.
2. Export in the Avro format so that any process outside Hadoop can also process it.

   Sub-option: Avro file thats GZip compressed.
3. Sqoop export the decompressed XML (text) to DB2 table.

The data that's exported could be in text format ~ 2 TB decompressed and 2 GB if its GZip compressed. I have not measured in Avro yet.

I am not sure which one to choose. First of all, is it a good idea to export this volume out?

Note: The client has also invested in Azure, just in case if its an option for the export (not sure if security policies would allow though).